# Can not install a poweroff service

Tags: service, windows-services, power-off

Actually I try to install a service called poweroff. This service normally will be installed from a software also called poweroff.

You find it here under old projects:

http://users.telenet.be/jbosman/applications.html

Until now on each pc i want to install the service I use an .cmd file with the content

> poweroff.exe shutdown -create_service -msg "This computer will be shut
>   down!" -warn -warntime 10 -wait 10 -force -allow_remote -remote_port
>   3210 -remote_pswd password

it creates the service so I can see it inside the services.msc program.

But now on one pc this command do nothing and when I try to create the service inside the poweroff program there comes an message "Access denied".

Because I logged on as administrator I think not that it is an right problem. 
Do anyone have an idea why the service will not created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was the access to the folder C:\Windows\System32.

After adding the poweroff.exe file to this folder the service could be created without problems.

Thanks to Jorgen Bosman for helping me to find this solution.